# When I pull data with the API in Redux, the same data is pulled over and over again

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I'm just learning React.js and redux concepts. I wanted to make a movie application with API. I was able to pull the data the way I wanted. However, the `movieContainer` in my `MovieItem.jsx` file appears on the screen twice, and every time I check my codes, this number increases. I couldn't find where I made a mistake.

The codes I use in my project are as follows:

------`MOVİELİSTSLİCE.JSX`-----

```
export const getMovie = createAsyncThunk("movieList/getMovie", async () => {
  
  const apiKey = '*********************';
  const apiUrl = `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?api_key=${apiKey}`;
  
  try {
    
    let response = await fetch(apiUrl);
    let json = await response.json();
    console.log(json);
    return json;
    
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error:', error);
    throw error;
  }
});

const movieListSlice = createSlice({
  name: "movieList",
  initialState: {
    movies: [], // Başlangıçta boş bir dizi
    status: null,
    error: null, // Yeni eklenen hata alanı
  },
  reducers: {}, // Eğer gelecekte reducer eklemek isterse bu alan kullanılabilir
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder
      .addCase(getMovie.pending, (state) => {
        state.status = "Fetching movies. Please wait a moment...";
      })
      .addCase(getMovie.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        let updatedMovies = state.movies.concat(action.payload);
        state.movies = updatedMovies;
        state.status = null;
      })
      .addCase(getMovie.rejected, (state, action) => {
        state.status = "Failed to fetch data...";
        state.error = action.error.message; // Hata mesajını sakla
      });
  },
});
```

------ `MOVİELİST.JSX ------`

```
const MovieList = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { movies, status } = useSelector((state) => state.movieList);
  console.log({ movies, status });
  useEffect(() => {
    if (movies.length === 0) {
      dispatch(getMovie());
    }
  }, [dispatch, movies]);

  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        {movies.map((movie) => {
          // return ;
          return <MovieItem {...movie} key={movie.id}/>;
        })}
        
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};
```

-------`MOVIEITEM.JSX`------

```
const MovieItem = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className="movieContainer">
      {props.results.slice(0, 20).map((movie, index) => (
        <div key={index} className='movieCard'>
          <h3 className='title'>{movie.title}</h3>
          <img src={`https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/${movie.poster_path}`} alt={movie.original_title}              width={400} height={200}/>

          <ul>
            <li><strong>Açıklama:</strong> {movie.overview}</li>
            <li><strong>Yayın Tarihi:</strong> {movie.release_date}</li> 
            <li><strong>Popülerlik:</strong> {movie.popularity}</li>  
          </ul>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

I'm waiting for your help :)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.